# reference in member class scope

Tags: c++, reference, scope

I came across this code, it does not work properly for the input 'bad', I know the reason, but I don´t understand it. I guess the problem is when the object is created. Could you guys explain it to me?

--Edited. Sorry, I put the & where it wasn´t.
const std::string& _badString; --> Here is where the problem is. If you run it with the argument 'bad', the exception is caught, but when printing the string, which should be 'bad', it only prints garbage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace
{
    const std::string bad = "bad";
}

class MyException
{
    const std::string& _badString;

public:
    MyException(const std::string& s):
    _badString(s)
    {
    }

    auto badString() const
    {
        return _badString;
    }
};


template<typename Arg>
void interpretArg(Arg arg)
{
    if (arg == bad)
    {
         throw MyException(arg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        try
        {
            interpretArg(argv[i]);
        }
        catch(const MyException& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "badString: " << e.badString() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should we know what means "work properly" for you?

Comment: Well, with properly I meant correct. When the argument is 'bad' it should catch the exception and print 'bad'

Answer (score 0):

A reference essentially acts as an alias. This means that unless you assign a reference to another object the compiler will not no where to find the specified information. In the case of your question the string object is not being assigned the address to another object, but instead is being assigned a string literal. In short a reference acts similar as a shortcut would in your computers filesystem, so when you use the shortcut it will actually use the information of the file the shortcut is linked to (Warning not a perfect comparison). This however is not a perfect analogy as a reference simply acts as a second name to the same point in your computer's memory.

```
const std::string& bad = "bad";
```

Consider the diagram below where both variables share the same memory address and are therefore essentially the same variable. You cannot assign a reference a value because you have not given it an address.

**Correct:**

```
                     / var_name1
0x756 < ------------/
^^ address in memory\
                     \ &var_name2 = var_name1; // Copying address.
```

**Incorrect:**

```
                          / "some_string"
no_address < ------------/
^^ address in memory     \
                          \ &var_name2 = "some_string"; // Assigning string
                                                        // Instead of an
                                                        // address.
```

**Note:** Your compiler will not use both of these variables and will instead replace both with a numerical address for a **single** object that can be populated with a value at runtime.

**Edit:** It is worth noting that using `const std::string &good = "hello";` is perfectly ok, as the compiler recognises that the value will not change and gives `good` it's own address.

Comment: Thanks bruffalobill for the explanation. I´m sorry I misplaced the & sign.